# CMake setting to Ninja rebuild when header change?

Tags: cmake, ninja

Apparently, Ninja has to be configured to treat headers as dependencies: https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#ref_headers.

How do I tell CMake to generate this into my build.ninja?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look into my `build.ninja` files generated with CMake for e.g. GCC I do have the necessary dependency file entries automatically generated (see `DEP_FILE`):

```
#=============================================================================
# Object build statements for EXECUTABLE target MyExe

build CMakeFiles/MyExe.dir/foo.cc.obj: CXX_COMPILER ../foo.cc
  DEP_FILE = CMakeFiles/MyExe.dir/foo.cc.obj.d
  FLAGS = -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wconversion
  OBJECT_DIR = CMakeFiles\MyExe.dir
  OBJECT_FILE_DIR = CMakeFiles\MyExe.dir
```

And the dependency checking works as expected. Just `touch` or change one of the header dependencies and `ninja` will automatically rebuild the necessary sources.

Comment: Thanks Florian. I was actually halfway through posting my own answer to explain that this was not my issue. In fact, I have been hit by a CMake bug having to do with [ and ] characters in my file names. I will accept your answer as it may prove helpful to others.

Comment: @user357269 You're welcome. And thanks for the warning about the potential file name pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

There is the file property `OBJECT_DEPENDS`, which can be used to specify the dependency on other files of any objects created from a specific file.

From [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_sf/OBJECT_DEPENDS.html):

> Additional files on which a compiled object file depends.
>
> Specifies a `;`-list of full-paths to files on which any object files compiled from this source file depend. On *Makefile Generators* and the **Ninja** generator an object file will be recompiled if any of the named files is newer than it. *Visual Studio Generators* and the *Xcode* generator cannot implement such compilation dependencies.
>
> This property need not be used to specify the dependency of a source file on a generated header file that it includes. Although the property was originally introduced for this purpose, it is no longer necessary. If the generated header file is created by a custom command in the same target as the source file, the automatic dependency scanning process will recognize the dependency. If the generated header file is created by another target, an inter-target dependency should be created with the `add_dependencies()` command (if one does not already exist due to linking relationships).

To set this property on a given source file, use:

```
set_property(SOURCE first.cpp second.cpp
             APPEND PROPERTY OBJECT_DEPENDS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/header1.h;${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/header2;${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/global_deps.h"
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not really what I'm looking for. It should be possible to do this automatically for all source files using the ninja dep/depfile commands (see my link above)